# The $n$-astrolabacus sequence.

Tags: combinatorics, recreational-mathematics

### The Details:

The [astrolabacus](https://youtu.be/Z-XAzV-20jw) is a puzzle said to have [$$A_3:=\frac{18!\times 2^{18}}{3!^6}=35,972,733,468,672,000$$](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/astrolab.htm) possible positions. Here is a GIF of the puzzle moving:

[image]

There are six segments that each contain six coloured balls: three per coloured half segment. Those segments can be moved as above and there are loops of $18$ balls that one can slide into different positions. There are four colours, like so:

[image]

A solution to the puzzle is described [here](http://www.powerstrike.net/puzzles/solutions/astrolabacus.htm).

> **Definition 1:** The $n$-astrolabacus is an astrolabacus where, instead of $3$ balls per half segment, there are $n$ balls.

Let $A_n$ be the number of different positions of the $n$-astrolabacus.

### The Question:

> What is $A_n$ in terms of $n\in\Bbb N$?

This sequence is not in the OEIS.

### My Attempt:

Well, when $n=3$, quoting [this article](https://www.jaapsch.net/puzzles/astrolab.htm), we have that

> [t]he puzzle is symmetrical, and remains so even when it changes its shape ($180$ degree rotational symmetry around a central axis). The balls therefore occur in pairs which remain opposite each other. There are four colours (red, blue, green, yellow), and the tunnels are coloured in such a way that every pair occurs exactly once.
>
> There are $18$ pairs coloured balls (sic) which can be permuted in $18!$ ways. The balls of a pair can also be swapped, so there are (at most) $18!\times 2^{18}$ ways to arrange them all. There are however indistinguishable ball pairs - there are $6$ pairs of colours, all occurring three times.

This gives the number quoted in the details.

Building on this, I conjecture that

$$A_n=\frac{2^{6n}(6n)!}{n!^6}.$$

Is this correct? It seems like it's just a matter of replacing $18$ by $6n$ in the argument above.

The expression $\frac{2^{6n}(6n)!}{n!^6}$ is an integer since $n!$ divides any product of $n$ consecutive integers.

Please help :)

Comment: This is cool!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Thank you, @Niing. I think so too.

Comment: Maybe you could add your $A_n$ in the OEIS and then specify that you conjecture that it returns the $n$-astrolabacus sequence for any positive integer $n$.

Comment: I just did so. Thank you for encouraging me, @Marco.

Comment: You are welcome.